# Sort without moving formatting

Tags: sorting, excel, formatting, vba

I have an Excel table in which multiple rows are given different coloured backgrounds by VBA macros. These background colours should be locked to the rows. My problem is that when the table is sorted by one column or another the background colours move as the data is reordered.

**Can I format in another way to stop this happening so that the cells remain locked?**

The code I use to format is:

```
For Each Row In rng.Rows

If Condition Then

   Row.Select

   cIndex = ColourIndex(colour)
   With Selection.Interior
       .ColorIndex = cIndex
   End With

End If    
Next
```

An example of my table is like this:

[image]
EDIT: Extra Code

```
Sub Quota(ByVal Type As String)

Dim records As Long
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Set sht2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

records = sht1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row - 5

Dim rng As Range
Dim rngRowCount As Long
Dim rLastCell As Range
Dim i As Long

sht2.Activate

'Last used cell
Set rLastCell = sht2.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
'All used columns except 1st
Set rng = sht2.Range(Cells(2, 1), rLastCell)
rng.Select
rngRowCount = rng.Rows.CountLarge

For i = 1 To rngRowCount

Dim valueAs String
Dim colour As String
Dim VarX As Long
Dim maxValue As Long

value= sht2.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
colour = sht2.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value

If Type = "A" Then
    VarX = sht2.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value
ElseIf Type = "B" Then
    VarX = sht2.Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
End If

maxValue = (records / 100) * VarX

ColourRows value, colour, maxValue

Next i

End Sub

Sub ColourRows(value As String, colour As String, maxValue As Long)

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Set sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
sht1.Activate

Dim rng As Range
Dim firstSixRowsOnwards As Range
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim usedColumns As Range
Dim usedColumnsString As String
Dim highlightedColumns As Range
Dim rngDataRowCount As Long
Dim performancevalueAs String
Dim cIndex As Integer
Dim count As Long

count = 0

Dim rLastCell As Range

'End row
rngDataRowCount = sht1.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
'First 6 rows
Set firstSixRowsOnwards = sht1.Range("A6:XFD1048576")
'Last column
lastColumn = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
'Used Range
Set rng = sht1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(rngDataRowCount, lastColumn))
'Used Columns
Set usedColumns = sht1.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1048576, lastColumn))

Set rng = Intersect(rng, firstSixRowsOnwards, usedColumns)

For Each Row In rng.Rows

    compareValue= Cells(Row.Row, 5)).Value

    If (InStr(1, value, compareValue, 1) Then

        Dim rowNumber As Long
        Row.Select

        If count < maxValue Then

            cIndex = ColourIndex(colour)
            With Selection.Interior
                .ColorIndex = cIndex
            End With

            count = count + 1

        Else

            cIndex = 3                      'red
            With Selection.Interior
                .ColorIndex = cIndex
            End With

        End If

    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you missed your table... if possible show what you have and what you would like to have

Comment: So in the example above rows 3 & 4 should always be red regardless of sorting, 6-8 always blue etc...

Comment: Can you please share the exact vba code which you use to fill in the rows? I want to know the criteria which you evaluate, and how you choose the colour to fill in the rows. I think that will help us find a way out.

Comment: Have added all the relevant code I think - let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: In few words, I would do it this way- 1) copy formatting of the `rng range` into new temporary workbook, 2) sort `rng range` using standard excel sorting features, 3) copy formatting back from temp workbook into your `rng range`. What do you think? Would you need any further assistance for that solution?

Comment: I need other users to be able to just use the standard sort functions so if this is the best solution I would need to automate the process so I'll explore the other answers on here further first - thanks though!

Comment: Hi KazJaw - using your approach how would I know when the sorting/filtering features have been used? I could use a general on_change macro but is there a simple way of only firing it for this particular change?

Comment: Hi KazJaw - your approach ended up being the best workaround solution to solve my problem. If you want to make an answer I'd be happy to mark it as solved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23547292/1967396 for a similar approach to @KazJaw's - except it's copying formats to an internal array, not a hidden worksheet.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that if you select your data by column and then sort (instead of a row limited range) then formatting will follow.

EDIT:

If you want to lock the formatting then use conditional formatting that is based on row number, e.g. ROW() = x or ROW() = range of values...

Tested: Use conditional formatting by formula set rule such as =ROW()=3 make sure excel does not double quote it for you, apply this to the entire data range. Row 3 will then always be formatted as you set here.

Setting in vba

```
Sub test()
  Range("A3").Select

  With Range("A3")
   .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ROW()=3"
   .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - Sorting by column still moves the background colour

Comment: oh my bad, I misread your original post and thought that was what you wanted

Comment: Tried it with conditional formatting based on getting the row number, using Rows(rowNumber).Select but didn't make a difference - is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Updated answer with more info - I just tried it and it worked, the format (I used a color fill) stayed locked to the define row number.

Comment: Could you post the VBA code in your answer so I can see exactly what you did?

Comment: The problem is the rows and colours are variable at time of setting background colours depending on the info in the spreadsheet so I can't just manually set it beforehand

Comment: Have put this in the loop like so: `For Each Row In rng.Rows If Condition Then cIndex = ColourIndex(colour) With Range(Row) .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ROW()=Row.Row" .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 46 End With` But I get a global Object failed error

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with CF, for example (top rule is >11):

[image: SO16274258 example]

*Edit - I inadvertently left out one rule*

the second down below uses `=ROW($A1)=11`:

[image: SO16274258 second example]

Comment: Is there a way to have this set by my VBA code dynamically once the code to determine which rows should be coloured which colours has run?

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

In this case, what I would do it one of the two things:

1. Conditional formatting. Needs lot of logics and manual steps so let us leave it.
2. A macro: Whenever you sort the data, please fire the following function

   ```
   Sub Option1()
   Dim row As Range
   Dim rowNum As Integer
   Dim tRange As Range

   'set range here: in your example, it is A2:D11

   Set tRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D11")

   'clear colors
   tRange.ClearFormats ' clears the previous format

   rowNum = 1

   For Each row In tRange.Rows

       Select Case rowNum
           Case 1, 2
               row.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' 1 and 2nd will be yellow
           Case 3, 4
               row.Interior.Color = 255 ' 3rd and 4th row will be red
           Case 5, 6
               row.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255) ' 5 and 6th row will be blue
           Case Else
               row.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) '' all the bottom row would be a Green row
       End Select
       rowNum = rowNum + 1
   Next row
   End Sub
   ```

Does it help?

Comment: My problem is a little more complex as I don't know which rows will pass the conditions or which colours they will be filled with before hand - this is pulled from the spreadsheet - have posted more extensive code now if that helps you help me

Comment: I tried using row.Interior as opposed to selection.interior as before but didn't help